# Loop Insertion into Dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, xpath

I'm a Cobol for Z/OS, AS/400, and I'm trying to learn new programming languages to do a few things at home. So I've picked up Python and started giving it a try.

But now I'm struck with a problem I can't understand why is happening, I've already researched a lot in many tutorials and in another questions about dictionaries around here, but still I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, any clarification be really appreciated.

So, what I'm trying to do is, I go into a page on a server using lxml, and return from it a list of texts, and their corresponding links, after that, I want to create a dictionary with both results(texts as keys and links as values), but things are not going on as I expected. Here is my actual code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://myexample.com.br/manga/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
namelist = tree.xpath('//div[@class="manga_list"]/ul/li/a/text()')
linklist = tree.xpath('//div[@class="manga_list"]/ul/li/a/@href')
ind1 = 0
listall = {}
while ind1 < len(namelist):
   print "Name", namelist[ind1]
   print "Link", linklist[ind1]
   listall[namelist[ind1]] = linklist[ind1]
   print "Key", listall.keys()[ind1]
   print "Index", ind1
   ind1 += 1
```

As you can see I've already added a few print lines inside my loop, so I could see in the terminal whatever was being used at the moment, and this is the result I've got, 
The keys keep repeating themselves and therefore they are not included, but the current name and link being used at the iteration of the loop are correct... So I'm really not getting what's happening in here...

```
Andres-MacBook-Pro:Documents Andre$ python teste.py
Name -6mm no Taboo
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/6mm_no_taboo/
Key -6mm no Taboo
Index 0
Name -Rain-
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/rain/
Key -6mm no Taboo
Index 1
Name -SINS-
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/sins/
Key -6mm no Taboo
Index 2
Name :REverSAL
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/reversal/
Key -6mm no Taboo
Index 3
Name ...Curtain
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/curtain/
Key -6mm no Taboo
Index 4
Name ...Junai no Seinen
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/junai_no_seinen/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 5
Name ...no Onna
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/no_onna/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 6
Name ...Seishunchuu!
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/seishunchuu/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 7
Name ...Virgin Love.
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/virgin_love/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 8
Name .925 (NISHI Uko)
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/925_nishi_uko/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 9
Name .hack//4koma
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/hack_4koma/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 10
Name .hack//Alcor
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/hack_alcor/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 11
Name .hack//G.U.+
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/hack_g_u/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 12
Name .Hack//GnU
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/hack_gnu/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 13
Name .hack//Link
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/hack_link/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 14
Name .hack//Tasogare no Udewa Densetsu
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/hack_tasogare_no_udewa_densetsu/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 15
Name .hack//XXXX
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/hack_xxxx/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 16
Name .traeH
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/traeh/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 17
Name 'Hajimete' Ageru!
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/hajimete_ageru/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 18
Name "Aishiteru", Uso Dakedo.
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/aishiteru_uso_dakedo/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 19
Name "Aoi" - Hikaru ga Chikyuu ni Itakoro......
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/aoi_hikaru_ga_chikyuu_ni_itakoro/
Key ...Junai no Seinen
Index 20
Name "Bungaku Shoujo" to Ue Kawaku Yuurei
Link http://myexample.com.br/manga/bungaku_shoujo_to_ue_kawaku_yuurei/
Key ...Virgin Love.
Index 21
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: After visualising the answer below, I understood that all the keys are actually being inserted, but no in the exact order in which they are in the webpage from the server. Since I'm Using the index of the page I thought if I used the same index value when opening the dictionary I would get the corresponding link on the page. 
So my question is how to order the dictionary  keys with the contents in the exact same order as they are being received?

Comment: If you want a dict to keep the insertion order you will need to use a collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries have no order, so the order in which you get back the keys (for the `dict.keys()` ) call may be different than what you expected ( which seems to be the case) . If you really want to check what all is there in the dictionary, you can try printing the complete dictionary (or maybe complete `dict.keys()` ). Example -

```
print "Listall", listall
```

Or

```
print "Keys",  listall.keys()
```

---

Also I am not 100% sure if the xpaths will always return the elements in the exact same order , but I would say its better to not risk it. You can just run the xpath like -

```
tree.xpath('//div[@class="manga_list"]/ul/li')
```

And then for each element in the result of above xpath, run two xpaths to get the text and corresponding href, Example -

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('http://myexample.com.br/manga/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
lilist = tree.xpath('//div[@class="manga_list"]/ul/li')
listall = {}
for lielem in lilist:
    name = lielem.xpath('./a/text()')
    link = lielem.xpath('./a/@href')
    print "Name", name
    print "Link", link
    listall[name] = link
    print "Keys", listall.keys()
```

If you want the namelist and linklist after this, just do - `listall.keys()` (for list of names) , and `listall.values()` (for list of values) .

---

If you want to keep the order in which the keys are inserted , you can use - [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) , Example -

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from collections import OrderedDict
page = requests.get('http://myexample.com.br/manga/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
lilist = tree.xpath('//div[@class="manga_list"]/ul/li')
listall = OrderedDict()
ind = 0
for lielem in lilist:
    name = lielem.xpath('./a/text()')
    link = lielem.xpath('./a/@href')
    print "Name", name
    print "Link", link
    listall[name] = link
    print "Keys", listall.keys()[ind]
    ind += 1
```